# Query data within KML

Tags: kml, query, kmz, bing-maps

Bing Maps v8 will not load multiple or complex KML files and allow me to query data within these shapes. Is there a work around for this?

[image]

Comment: Can you use Google Earth Pro?

Comment: What kind of query do you want to make? If your kml has polygons and you want to query pushpin data on the map that intersects, that can be done with a bit of code. Please add details in your question on what you are trying to achieve.